# How use a patch that fixed a bug

Tags: qt

I'm getting crazy with a bad memory access in a qt program when i'm using `qglwidget::rendertext` function. My program is super simple, I'm only one pointer, but the crash doesn't seem relate to that because the debugger stops sometimes when i call rendertext, sometimes when i close the programs. i'm not experienced c++ programmer and this is getting me crazy.

but i've found this [BUG REPORT](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-26649). It seems recent (`Updated:  25/Apr/13 8:47 AM`) and due to the fact I don't know what to do with this bad memory access i think it worths to give it a try.

the solution patch is posted [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,54389) but i don't know what to do.. do i have to recompile all qt 4.8? only the opengl part? can i avoid to recompile everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the directory where you compiled Qt and change the file `qt/src/opengl/qpaintengine_opengl.cpp`.  Make the changes that the author made, or download the author's file and replace it in your source directory.  Change directory to the main qt directory and run `make`.  Be sure not to re-run `./configure` before you do the `make` or it will rebuild the whole thing.

After `make` has finished, run `sudo make install` and it will put the newly compiled `QPaintEngine` module into your install directory.  Unfortunately, I don't know if this will work if you have a number of configurations (like static libraries), but it's worth a try.

I have done this with modules in QtMobility hundreds of times.  You also have to remember that you have a Frankenstein's Monster version of Qt now, and when you upgrade remember to re-patch if the change was not committed to the newest build.

Hope this helps.